# HRESULT E_FAIL when selecting a DataGrid row

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, silverlight-4.0

I'm in a tight spot with this error...

I have a `DataGrid` with some data. Based on some other parameters defined by the user, my application loads data in the background.

So far, everything worked fine. However, I've stumbled upon the following error today:

```
Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
```

This error appeared completely out of the blue; I was using my application and then, suddenly, this appeared when I selected a new row. It consistently appears for a specific row with specific application parameters, and so far hasn't appeared in any other case.

The error doesn't come with a `StackTrace` (which is `null`) and neither with an `InnerException`.

As such, I'm a bit bewildered and don't quite know what to do. I can't post the entire application here, and that error gives me absolutely nothing to go on. It does, however, cause the entire application to stop working (when no debugger is attached the application just "vanishes").

What should I do with this?

PS. The application is an Azure Silverlight application, but this happens regardless if I run it on the Dev. fabric or if it's online. But my gut tells me it's an issue with Silverlight itself, and not with Azure.

Comment: Contact Microsoft Support for this.

Comment: Same thing here although i know it is caused by trying to use the official DataGridRow template. Just so you know, you can get the call stack if you choose the copy to clipboard button. In my case last 2 calls are the following: System.Exception crossed a native/managed boundary
  Message=Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
  StackTrace:
       στις MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckHResult(UInt32 hr)
       στις MS.Internal.XcpImports.UIElement_Measure(UIElement element, Size availableSize)